# Lift Squeryl-Record select with google user id

Tags: scala, record, lift, squeryl

I want to identify a user using the Google OAuth service. This returns a `googleId` which is 2^67 so it does not fit into the long datatype which I am currently using as the primary key in my table. Because of this I wanted to store the googleId in a StringField.

However, this does not function because I can not get the Where clause working:
    `where(u.googleId.is === id)`
produces the error `value === is not a member of u.googleId.MyType`.

I defined it like this:

```
val googleId = new StringField(this, "")
```

How can I select the data using a StringField in the where clause?

Thanks in advance

Flo

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `BigDecimal` do the trick? http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html

Also, I'm not sure about the syntax, isn't it supposed to be ?:

```
where(u.googleId == "hello there")
```

I'm using pure squeryl and pure liftweb, so I'm not sure..

Comment: Thanks so far. I will try it when I'm at home and tell when it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by importing `org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._` as described here [Squeryl Schema Definition](http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html)

I then set the googleId to be of type `StringField`

```
val googleId = new StringField(this,"")
```

Now I have to add a `.~` to the field because else it will be interpreted as `String` not as `TypedExpressionNode[Int]`.

Now the following statement works:

```
where(u.googleId.is.~ === id) select (u))
```